# Import Customer Refund scenario and got error 'Document is out of balance'

Tags: acumatica

I try to import customer refund scenario but it got error as "Document is out of balance" like the below picture:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you have some applications imported along with Customer Refund?
In Acumatica you are not allowed to create Customer Refund that is not fully applied to some document.
So, if you are trying to create Customer refund without any applications(or if sum of application amounts is not equal to refund amount), you'll get this error.

So, either create document along with applications or create document On Hold(that is Hold checkbox selected).

Document having On Hold status considered as draft and can be saved unbalanced.

Comment: I've imported prepayment first and then I want to import customer refund to apply with that document. But on Payments and Applications screen it also got error "Document out of balance" with Payment Amount when I apply some documents so that's why on import scenario did error too.